# Can't we create Managed Table with Foreign key in Azure data lake

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-data-lake

I was looking into  [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt706196.aspx) while creating tables but so far example didn't mentioned ,how to add foreign key while creating table. Also I check documentation for [Alter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/mt706199.aspx) statement too, but same goes with this too

```
  CREATE TABLE Brand (
            BrandId          int,            
            Name         string,
            AddressId           int,
            SuperAdminDetails string,
           CONSTRAINT FK_Address FOREIGN KEY (AddressId) REFERENCES Address(AddressId) ,

            INDEX Brand_idx CLUSTERED (BrandId ASC) 
                  PARTITIONED BY HASH (BrandId)
  );


  // ALTER TABLE Brand ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Address FOREIGN KEY (AddressId) REFERENCES Address(AddressId) ;
```

Error  While Executing Above USQL

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

U-SQL as per the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt706196.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) does not currently support foreign keys.  If you require this functionality consider hosting your data in an Azure SQL Database (which does support foreign keys) and using [federated queries](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/jorg_klein/archive/2016/06/17/setup-azure-data-lake-analytics-federated-u-sql-queries-to-azure-sql-database.aspx) to query the data where it lives.  Alternately consider making a feedback request:

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/327234-data-lake/filters/hot?page=2

Comment: Thanks for the feedback link.